# How do I get HTML button value to pass as a parameter to my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple buttons corresponding to multiple text areas to clear. I need to send to have a function to handle all of these buttons and handle each seperately

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getUniqueButtonValue(value)
        {
            alert(value);
            $("value").hide();
        }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

         <button id=someUinqueId value=something>Clear Selection</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting aside the fact that you're placing a unique id in the `value` attribute rather than the `id` attribute... here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSsPe/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var me = $(this);
        // do whatever with me
        alert(me.val());
        me.hide();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be numerous problems with the code you've posted in your question. Firstly, (unless you're using `<!DOCTYPE html>` as your doctype) you can't have `id` values starting with a number.

Secondly, the jQuery (I'm assuming it's jQuery and not some other JS library) in your `getUniqueButtonValue` function is not going to work, because the selector is going to look for a `value` element, which is unlikely to exist.

I'm assuming that the `value` attribute of your `button` is meant to correspond to the `id` of another element, which you want to hide when the button is clicked.

As you have what appears to be jQuery code in your example, I will give you a jQuery solution to this, as it's far simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        alert(this.value);
        $("#" + this.value).hide();
    });
});
```

Also, you don't close your `body` tag, but I'm guessing that's just a mistake in copying and pasting the code into the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<button id=123 value=uniqueId545 onclick="javascript:getUniqueButtonValue($(this).val());">Clear Selection</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#123").click(function(){
    getUniqueButtonValue($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: well I need one function to handle all buttons. So if i clear clear on button id=345 it clears its section and not another section handled by button id=567

Comment: Give the buttons a class and use the code in this answer, but with `$(".buttonClass")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. If i guess correctly this is what you want (ids shouldn't begin with a number so I put an 'a' before the 123:

```
$("#a123").click(function(){
    getUniqueButtonValue($("#a123").getAttribute('value');
}
function getUniqueButtonValue(value)
{
        alert(value);
        $("#"+value).hide();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

     <button id=123 value=uniqueId545>Clear Selection</button>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself a lot of work by trying:

```
<button class="clearbutton" value="#Foo">Clear Foo</button>
<input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" />
```

With the following JavaScript:

```
$('.clearbutton').click(function(e) {
    $($(this).val()).val('');
});
```