# call function with parameter unobstrusively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, parameter-passing

I have a functional code, but would like to improve it for the sake of learning.

I did quite a lot of research and only found a solution using jQuery, but as i'm still a beginer I would like to make in in plain js first.
[[How do I get HTML button value to pass as a parameter to my javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205148/how-do-i-get-html-button-value-to-pass-as-a-parameter-to-my-javascript])

Basically, I have a list, and I want each entry of this list to call a function with a given parameter, being a natural number.

Among the classic / **obstrusive** techniques we have:

```
<li><a href="#" id="0" class="myClass" onclick="return myFunction(0);" >clickMe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="1" class="myClass" onclick="return myFunction(1);" >clickMe</a></li>
...
```

or

```
<li><a href="javascript:myFunction(0)" id="0" class="myClass">ClickMe</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:myFunction(1)" id="1" class="myClass">ClickMe</a></li>
...
```

and

```
<li><button class="myClass" onClick="return myFunction(0);">ClickMe</button></li>
...
```

wich indeed call `myFunction()` with the parameter set to `0, 1` and so on.

But I've read that it wasn't recomended to do so as

- I'm using the `<a>` tag while I'm not intending to link anywhere.
- it mixes HTML and Javascript and that separation of concern is the way to go whenever possible

Then there is the **unobstrusive** way

```
<li><button id="0" class="myClass">clickMe</button></li>
```

completed by

```
document.getElementById("0").onclick = function (){myFunction()}
```

This works, but I can't find a way to set my parametter. 
If, for instance, I add a `value="0"` attribute to my button, or `myVar="0"`, I can't use `value` as a variable as it isn't declared, and it doesn't set the new value of `myVar`, thus `myFunction` is called with the wrong parameter being `myVar="myVarPreviousValue"`

Using **GetElementsByClassName** : **EDIT**: updated

Previously we used `document.getElementById`, however this may be very inconvinient if the list is long as we would have to create an event listner for every button. In such context, the use of `document.getElementsByClassName` seems appropriate.

As pointed by [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) there's a nice explaination for the use of this method here [Document.getElementsByClassName not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155947/document-getelementbyclassname-not-working).

However this thread can be completed by precising how to get a variable value that is set in the elements of a given class in order to call a function with a given parameter

**Bottom line question**

How to, **unobstrusivelly**, **call a function with a given parameter** when the user **click** on some html content that have a **given class** (could be a `<li>`, `<button>`, `<span>`, `<div>`  as you think is best)

Thank's in advance
J.

**Edit** : updated the question related to the use of getElementsByClassName

Comment: There is no `getElementByClassName`.....

Comment: Use `addEventListener()` method

Comment: Why not `document.querySelectorAll('.myClass')` or `document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')` as @epascarello so obviously pointed out :)

Comment: add in your <a> a data-parameter='X' attribute. You can take its value from jquery.on("click", ...) as $(this).data("parameter")

Comment: Thank's everyone
@epascarello : I'm not sure people will understand your comment, but indeed, getElementByClassName have to be used following a certain way, I upadate my post;
@Icepickle : yes I use `document.getElement.ByClassName and not `getElement.ByClassName`, I've upadated the post;
@A.Wolff : When I use `addEventListener` my function is called on page load and I don't whant that;
@Tistkle : using `<a>` to call a function without the need to link to somewhere else is apparently a bad practice.

Comment: just add the data parameter to your li, then, and point the $.on("click") to your li, or your button, if you prefer...

Comment: @jbonlinea "*getElement* **s** *ByClassName*" <-- I was not referring to `document`

Comment: And if you r function is called on page load, that means someone is using it wrong... You are calling the method, not assigning a reference to it.

Comment: @epascarello : oh !!!  This typo isn't in my original code as there is auto-complete ! ; correcting this here as well !thak's

Comment: Question is still a dupe of looping over the collection... amazed it is reopened... All you had to do was read the id when the item was clicked or read the data attribute.

Answer (score 2):

> Then there is the unobstrusive way
>
> ```
> <li><button id="0" class="myClass">clickMe</a></li>
> ```
>
> completed by
>
> ```
>  document.getElementById("0").onclick = function (){myFunction()}
> ```

(Side note: You have `<button ...></a>` there, probably meant `</button>` at the end.)

In that specific case, just

```
document.getElementById("0").onclick = function (){ myFunction(0); };
// ------------------------------------------------------------^
```

...but I'd always advocate `addEventListener` instead, so the code plays nicely with others:

```
document.getElementById("0").addEventListener("click", function (){ myFunction(0); }, false);
```

(If you have to support obsolete browsers like IE8, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799296/js-li-tag-onclick-not-working-on-ie8/23799448#23799448) has a cross-platform `hookEvent` you can use instead of `addEventListener`.)

If you want to use the **same** handler and put the argument on the element, you can use the `id` or a `data-*` attribute:

```
 <li><button id="0" data-value="0" class="myClass">clickMe</button></li>
```

completed by

```
document.getElementById("0").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
```

then

```
function myFunction() {
    var parameter = this.getAttribute("data-value");
    // or var parameter = this.id;
    // ...
}
```

Here's an example using `querySelectorAll` to handle all `button` elements with a `data-value` attribute, and showing the `data-value` attribute when clicked:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-value]");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
});
function handler() {
  console.log("Value: " + this.getAttribute("data-value"));
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-value="one">I'm 'one'</button>
<button type="button" data-value="two">I'm 'two'</button>
<button type="button" data-value="three">I'm 'three'</button>
<button type="button" data-value="four">I'm 'four'</button>
```

---

Side note: While it's valid HTML, I would generally avoid starting an `id` value with a digit, because although they work with `getElementById`, they're awkward to use in CSS selectors (`#0` is invalid, for instance).

Comment: Hi, tanks for the proposals, works like a charm ! Now it seems that to be the least obtrusive as possible it would be recommended to use a different handler for each element, but maybe there are also cases when setting the parameter in the element and use the same handler is best?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a predefined function, you can do

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass");
for (var i=0;i< elements.length;i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = myFunction;
}
```

and use a data-attribute to pass the data or this.id if that is enough

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
  e.stopPropagation(); // cancel event bubbling 
  console.log(this.id, this.getAttribute("data-val")||this.value);
}
window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = myFunction;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="link0" data-val="value 0" class="myClass">clickMe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="link1" data-val="value 1" class="myClass">clickMe</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><button type="button" id="but0" value="value 0" class="myClass">clickMe</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" id="but1" value="value 1" class="myClass">clickMe</button></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li id="link0" data-val="value 0" class="myClass">clickMe</li>
  <li id="link1" data-val="value 1" class="myClass">clickMe</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: By all means remove the a and put the class and id/attribute on the li - perhaps with a css pointer assigned - see 3rd ul

Comment: excellent the third option lis almost exactly what I'm looking for, but bump into issue with nested lists : 1) correct in html terms `<ul><li></li><li*><ul><li></li></ul></li*></ul>` ; 2) not correct in html terms `<ul><li></li><li*></li*><ul><li></li></ul></ul>`; the difference is marked by an *;  Of course in both case cliking on the list element return the right value, but in the first one it imediatly update the value to the parent item marked *  not sure how to solve this, but your code remain great !

Comment: Replace e.preventDefault(); used for links and submissions to  e.stopPropagation();

Comment: excellent ! As I'm only using `<li>` and not `<a>` I indeed removed `e.preventDefault();` ; now your script works fine but I still have a css issue, as the whole `<li>a<ul><li>b</li></ul></li>` get the `:hover`link style and not solely the `<li>` I'm on...

Comment: Then perhaps :focus or onfocus

Comment: Hi thank for your great input, very thoughtful for me, in the end for cross browser compatibility the only viable solution I've found to feeding nested list is to place their content in a dedicated span class. In this context I would think that the use of a button might be recommended as it is dedicated to be clicked rather than turn a span or a list into a clickable friendly design through CSS? Still super complete and helpful answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it got reopened, I will answer.

There is no `getElementByClassName` there is a `getElementsByClassName`. You can not just bind to the collection directly. You would need to loop over the live html collection to add the events.

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(this.getAttribute("data-id"));
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="0" class="myClass">ClickMe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="1" class="myClass">ClickMe</a></li>
</ul>
```

The easy answer is event delegation, one click event on the parent element, look at the event object for what was clicked and you have the element. Read the data attribute or id and you have the number.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("myList");
list.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   console.log(e.target.getAttribute("data-id"));
});
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="0" class="myClass">ClickMe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="1" class="myClass">ClickMe</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank's for your reply, indeed my question was partially answered as the post you mentionned only deals with class, and do not inform the case of setting a var value and calling a function with this value as parameter; Apart from that the idea of this post was to use unobstrusive code, and avoid the use of <a> as I don't intend to link anywhere

Comment: What do links have to do with it? You can have a link or a button. Makes things work with tab on the keyboard for navigation.

Comment: but using <a href="#"> might be right I just have seen than it shouls be avoided, but you know better thant me ;-)

Comment: I've read that and want to improve my code and skill [link(]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/which-href-value-to-use-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)